# Given $f(x)$, how does one find $f'(a)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't know how to go about solving this problem. I was given $f(x)=12$, and told to find $f'(4)$. I tried using the equation of a tangent line, but that didn't work. Any suggestions or tips? This is probably a simple question but I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: When you write $f(x) = 12$, do you mean that $f(4) = 12$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(4)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(4+h)-f(4)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{12-12}{h}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A constant functions rate of change at any point is $0$. So $f(x)=12$  is a constant and so the derivative is $0$ everywhere. So you have that $f'(4)=0$.